# LaTeX equivalent of an output routine

Tags: page-breaking, page

I would like to collect material and when a page is full I'd like to put it into a box with some heading and other decorations.

In Plain TeX I would use an output routine for this:

```
\count0=1
\hsize=140mm
\vsize=200mm

\output={\shipout\hbox{
  \vbox to297mm{
    \hrule
    \hbox{\vrule\hskip3mm\vbox{\vskip2mm
    \ifnum\count0 = 1
      {\bf Page 1: First page heading}
    \else
      {\bf Page \the\count0: Further page}
    \fi    
    \vskip2mm
    \unvbox255
    \vfill
    }\hskip3mm\vrule}
    \hrule
  }
}
\global\advance\count0 by 1}

\vbox to 40mm{Some content\vfill}
\vbox to 40mm{Some content\vfill}
\vbox to 40mm{Some content\vfill}
\vbox to 40mm{Some content\vfill}
\vbox to 40mm{Some content\vfill}
\vbox to 40mm{Some content\vfill}
\vbox to 40mm{Some content\vfill}
\bye
```

which gives me the desired result (showing page 2 here):

[image: result]

Can I do something similar in LaTeX?

Just adding my example from above to a LaTeX document didn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\output={\shipout\hbox{
  \vbox to297mm{
    \hrule
    \hbox{\vrule\hskip3mm\vbox{\vskip2mm
    Header
    \vskip2mm
    \unvbox255
    \vfill
    }\hskip3mm\vrule}
    \hrule
  }
}}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> Output routine didn't use all of \box255.

Comment: Have you tried using your `\output` code in LaTeX?

Comment: Hm, it actually kind of does the same thing if I put it in a document environment, with simple paragraphs of text at least. But when I start putting less simple things like a tikzpicture into the page, it breaks.

Comment: Please add a sample document with the code that doesn't work for you

Comment: I'm not sure that I really understand what you are trying to do, but it looks like something that I would do with tcolorbox.

Comment: @siracusa Done.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The box is just an example for something I might put *around* the actual page contents.

Comment: you could define a new output routine but it isn't at all clear that you need to do so, the normal way to do this in latex is just to define a custom page style, which really is just specifying code to be called at the top and bottom of the page box by latex's output routine

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That seems to be what I'm looking for, how can I do that? I found examples of `\newpagestyle` but they use `\sethead` and `\setfoot` which don't seem to allow me to run arbitrary code (to add the box for example).

Comment: in the page head you can put a 0-sized picture `\begin{picture}(0,0)...\end{picture}` so then within that you can `\put` any lines or boxes or images or anything else anywhere on the page. there are also several packages wrapping this up in nicer syntax (look at the `esopic` package for example) anything you put this way in the page head will be a background of any text on the page, if you do the same in the foot it will over-print text in the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Isn't there anything where I can actually work with the current page material (like `\unvbox255`) and just add some code around it? In my example the height of the box depends on that actual content height, I can't do that with a picture, can I?